# how to make my domain public?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, web-server, web-hosting, jboss

I have my web application running in jboss on my pc. But it is accessible only in localhost. I have seen in sites like godaddy, they talk about giving a domain name to your site. But where is the mapping actually done. And will I be able to use my pc it self as the server or will I hae to deploy the application on godaddy's server.
 My application only stores resources i.e it only contains `servlets`. It only used to process the incoming data and send responses. So any domain name is fine(because no one will be visiting the domain from the browser). The client is an android phone. So what are the steps I should take to make this web application be `accessible on the internet`?

Comment: Get yourself a dynamic DNS domain name, and open up the ports on your firewall.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is pretty far below the standard for SF - If you want to host this on your own system you need to know enough to make that system accessible on the public internet (you don't even tell us enough to help you with that). If this is for any kind of business you are in need of the services of a professional, and if it's not your question would be better asked on Super User, though as currently posed they probably can't help much either...

Answer (score 1):

If this is for some commercial service you'll need to get a hosted space somewhere and run this on a server.  Then you can register and point a domain name to the IP for resolution in the client app.  If this is a test or toy, then a dynamic DNS name and opening up the ports (assuming they are not blocked by your ISP) is an acceptable route

Answer (score -1):

Your understanding of basic networking concepts is nearly nonexistent. I recommend some very basic materials like [this](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/internet.htm) to get you on your feet.

Domain registrars (like GoDaddy) offer you the ability to register a domain name, like website.com. That is all they do. DNS turns those names into IP addresses. It does not make your locally-hosted application accessible from the Internet. That will require configuration on your end.

To make your application accessible from the Internet, you will (probably) need to set up NAT on your gateway (router) to forward traffic from the outside world in to your host behind the gateway. You can continue to host it on your PC. I don't recommend trying to do this yourself, as your current grasp of the concepts involved suggests the need for a professional.

Comment: I have brushed up my concepts. I don't own a router. How can I buy a static ip? Is it really necessary to buy a static ip or is there some other way to come around it. I don't think my service provider(Reliance) will provide me with a static ip. The ip address changes each time.